# Toggle script in jQuery 1.9.1

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just upgraded a site to 1.9.1 and the scipt below dont work anymore:

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").toggle(function() {
        $(this).text('Hide content');
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('Show content');
    });
    $('#button').click(function(){
       $("#content_div").slideToggle("medium");
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="button">Show content</a>
```

I am not so good at jQuery so I hope somebody can help me with this script, I´ll appreciate if a answer contains a explanation of the solution (trying to learn jQuery).

Thanks!

Comment: Your toggle parameters don't make sense ( http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ ) what are you trying to accomplish with toggle?

Comment: When click at button #button the #content_div slideToggle and the text "Show content" in the button changes to "Hide content".

Comment: Unless you are using a library that needs jQuery 1.9.1 there really isn't any need to upgrade...

Comment: There is other jquery functions in the site, its better to keep the site and the code updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following gives you the full functionality that you're looking for. It feels self-explanatory to me, but then again, I wrote it haha. So let me know if it makes sense and does what you need it to do :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button').click(function(){
            var txt = "Show Content";
            if ($("#button").html()==txt)
            {
                txt = "Hide content";
            }
            $("#button").html(txt);


            $("#content_div").slideToggle("medium");
        });
    });
```

Comment: @RCNeil I'm not sure. There actually used to be two different `.toggle()` functions, which can be confusing and is possibly the reason for the deprecation. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) is the version that is still valid. (and [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)'s the deprecated one).

Comment: that's awesome to know!  I wasn't aware there was still a functional one, perhaps I can still use it to server my purpose.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This functionality of `.toggle` was removed in jQuery 1.9](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

There are a variety of ways to handle this.  One is to simply keep track of the click state of the object internally.

```
$("#button").on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
        //functionality state 2
    }
    else {
        //functionality state 1
    }
    $(this).data('clicked', function (_, data) { return !data; });
});
```

You can even manage more than two states using integers and modulo.

Comment: Ok I see. But how to implement this code? The text-toggle script in one state and the slide-toggle in another?

Comment: @Wobot sure .. you can bind two different click events

Comment: I understand how you mean but dont manage to get it to work. I place the .toggle(function) part in one state and the .slideToggle part in another. There issent any way thats more simialr to my current script?

Comment: @Wobot the toggle and the slide parts are not for separate states; this bind is to handle both of the *toggle* states.  The slide callback is irrespective of all of that